# In Scala, why does Array("1") ++ "-3" output Array[Any] = Array(1, -, 3)?

Tags: scala

Why in Scala 2.12.6 does `Array("1") ++ "-3"` output `res1: Array[Any] = Array(1, -, 3)`?

How do I get the result `Array("1", "-3")`?

Comment: `Array("1") ++ Array("-3")`

Comment: should i use ":+"?  if the second part is a String

Comment: That's one way of doing it.

Comment: The `++` method concatenates two sequences. String isn't a sequence, so Scala applies an [implicit conversion](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/Predef$.html#augmentString(x:String):scala.collection.immutable.StringOps), i.e. transforms it to a **sequence** of **chars**.

Comment: This still kind of blows my mind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`++` is `binary operator`(also called method) that is used to concatenate two collections.eg. `Array`s or `List`s.
If the first operand is an `Array`, the result defaults to `Array`.
If the first operand is a `List`, the result defaults to `List`.

The compiler, by default, treats `"-3"` as `String`.
All Strings can be treated as collections also (by implicit conversions when required ). But what type of collection? Is it `Array`? Is it `List`? depends on its usage with the type of collection it is operated on.

For Example,
    While using it as `Array("1") ++ "-3"`, `the String` `"-3"` by default will be treated by the compiler as `Array[Char]` because the first operand of `++` is an `Array` ( though the type of elements will be always `Char` by default , by the compiler)
    While using it as `List("1") ++ "-3"`, `the String` `"-3"` by default will be treated as `List[Char]` because the first operand of `++` is a `List` ( though the type of elements will be always `Char` by default , by the compiler)

When the `++` operator encounters both operands are collections of different types of elements, their closest `super-type` in `type-hierarchy`, will be the type of elements of the resultant collection.
    The `super-type` of `String`, which is the type of elements of first operand(collection) and `Char`, 
which is the type of elements of second operand(collection) is `Any`. 
So the 
result of  `Array("1") ++ "-3"` is `Array[Any]`.

If you want to add the `String` `"-3"` as an element to the collection, `Array("1")`, then you must add it as an element to this collection. There is another method ie., `:+` or `+:` to append or prepend an element to the collection as below.

***To append to the collection:***

```
scala> Array("1") :+ "-3"
res6: Array[String] = Array(1, -3)
```

***To prepend to the collection:***

```
scala> "-3" +: Array("1")
res7: Array[String] = Array(-3, 1)
```

*Another way of doing the above is as below(converting element to a collection and using `++` method):*

```
scala> Array("1") ++ Array("-3")
res9: Array[String] = Array(1, -3)

scala> Array("-3") ++ Array("1")
res10: Array[String] = Array(-3, 1)

scala>
```

Answer (score 8):

The `++` operator concatenates two Lists (or other collections) together. As a String is essentially just a list of Chars, as @senjin.hajrulahovic points out the compiler treats it this way (and returns an `Array[Any]`.

You can get around this in multiple ways. For example, `Array("1") ++ Array("-3")` (to add two arrays together) or `Array("1") :+ "-3"` to put the value on the end of the Array.

Answer (score 3):

Because scala treats `"-3"` as a sequence of chars `'-'` and `'3'`.

If you want to append the string "-3" as one element use `:+`.

Comment: should i use ":+"?

Comment: Yes. It returns the result you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found the explanation [here](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/array-class-methods-examples-syntax#toc_8).

The following is an excerpt (verbatim) from there.

> #### How to add (append and prepend) elements to an Array
>
> You can’t resize a Scala `Array`, but you can use these operators
>   (methods) to append and prepend elements to an array while assigning
>   the result to a new variable:
>
> ```
> ┌──────────────────────────┬─────────────────┬──────────────────────────────┐
> │ Method                   │  Description    │  Example                     │
> ├──────────────────────────┼─────────────────┼──────────────────────────────┤
> │ :+                       │ append 1 item   │ oldArray :+ e                │
> ├──────────────────────────┼─────────────────┼──────────────────────────────┤
> │ ++                       │ append N items  │ oldArray ++ newArray         │
> ├──────────────────────────┼─────────────────┼──────────────────────────────┤
> │ +:                       │ prepend 1 item  │ e +: oldArray                │
> ├──────────────────────────┼─────────────────┼──────────────────────────────┤
> │ ++:                      │ prepend N items │ newArray ++: oldArray        │
> └──────────────────────────┴─────────────────┴──────────────────────────────┘
> ```
>
> ***Append and prepend examples***
>
> These examples show how to use those methods to append and prepend
>   elements to an `Array`:
>
> ```scala
> val v1 = Array(4,5,6)         // Array[Int] = Array(4, 5, 6)
> val v2 = v1 :+ 7              // Array(4, 5, 6, 7)
> val v3 = v2 ++ Array(8,9)     // Array(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
>
> val v4 = 3 +: v3              // Array(3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
> val v5 = Array(1,2) ++: v4    // Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I have a tip here that has helped me. To remember what "append" operators do what, think of `:+` or `+:`, which append one element to a list, as it being "*the side of the operator that is the colon side - is the 'collection' side.*"  This tells you which operand represents what and also that there is a reason to differentiate.

Comment: I imagine the colon as glue and the plus as a pointy thing the element is skewered on. (Well, it helps me.)